# Logging security events in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, logins, logs, password

I need to log events of admin changing someone's password, and user changing his password. How do I do that?
I've found a [nice solution](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2708/tracking-login-password-changes-in-sql-server/) based on Service Broker, however the resulting table only contains the login of account that made the change, not the affected account.
Could anyone tell me how to alter this part

```
INSERT dbo.PasswordChangeLog(LoginName) 
SELECT @message_body.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'sysname');
```

So that I'd insert the *object* of password change, too? I know I will have to `ALTER dbo.PasswordChangeLog` to add an extra column, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract much more data from the event instance in the Service Broker message to store in the table. Specifically, **TargetLoginName** should bring back the affected user for you, something like this should work:

```
SELECT @message_body.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'sysname') AS [ActioningLogin],
  @message_body.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TargetLoginName)[1]', 'sysname') AS [AffectedLogin]
```

[More info here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/audit-login-change-password-event-class?view=sql-server-ver15)